# Pandas - Extracting multiple data from a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my Dataframe that has some data in the below format:

```
['com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@339ba62[id=001,rapidViewId=24,state=CLOSED,name=proj_a,goal=,startDate=2015-01-01T04:00:26.231Z,endDate=2015-01-13T14:36:00.000Z,completeDate=2015-02-13T14:07:09.739Z,sequence=001]
```

I was trying to pull `id` value from the above column which I was able to do using the below method:

```
df['id'] = df['value'].astype(str).str.split('id').str[1]
df['id'] = df['id'].str.split(',').str[0]
df['id'] = df['id'].str.split('=').str[1]
```

I now have a problem wherein the same field has multiple such values as shown below:

```
['com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@339ba62[id=001,rapidViewId=24,
state=CLOSED,name=proj_a,goal=,startDate=2015-01-01T04:00:26.231Z,endDate=2015-01-13T14:36:00.000Z,
completeDate=2015-02-13T14:07:09.739Z,sequence=001]', 
'com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@10b316d8[id=002,rapidViewId=24,
state=CLOSED,name=proj_b,goal=,startDate=2016-01-01T04:00:26.231Z,
endDate= 2016-01-13T14:36:00.000Z,completeDate= 2016-02-13T14:07:09.739Z,sequence=002]', 
'com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@2a13ba77[id=003,
rapidViewId=24,state=CLOSED,name=proj_c,goal=,
startDate= 2017-01-01T04:00:26.231Z,endDate= 2017-01-13T14:36:00.000Z,
completeDate= 2017-02-13T14:07:09.739Z,sequence=003]',
 'com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@76d3dba0[id=004,rapidViewId=24,
state=CLOSED,name=proj_d,goal=,startDate=2018-01-01T04:00:26.231Z,
endDate= 2018-01-13T14:36:00.000Z,completeDate= 2018-02-13T14:07:09.739Z,sequence=004]', 'com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@307a51a2[id=005,
rapidViewId=24,state=CLOSED,name=proj_e,goal=,startDate=2019-01-01T04:00:26.231Z,
endDate= 2019-01-13T14:36:00.000Z,completeDate= 2019-02-13T14:07:09.739Z,sequence=005]']
```

Expected output :

```
001,002,003,004,005
```

I am trying to extract values corresponding to id and store them in a single field

Comment: Your data is not copy and pasteable. Try it for yourself. You didnt format your text well with the `'`.

Comment: @Erfan, forgot to close the content I tried to paste. I have updated it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just take the first three characters after every `id=`. 
Skip the first element because that is what comes before the first `id=`.

```
df["id"] = [x[:3] for x in df["value"].astype(str).split("id=")[1:]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.findall`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"value": ['com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@339ba62[id=001,rapidViewId=24,state=CLOSED,name=proj_a,goal=,startDate=2015-01-01T04:00:26.231Z,endDate=2015-01-13T14:36:00.000Z,completeDate=2015-02-13T14:07:09.739Z,sequence=001]', 'com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@10b316d8[id=002,rapidViewId=24,state=CLOSED,name=proj_b,goal=,startDate=2016-01-01T04:00:26.231Z,endDate= 2016-01-13T14:36:00.000Z,completeDate= 2016-02-13T14:07:09.739Z,sequence=002]', 'com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@2a13ba77[id=003,rapidViewId=24,state=CLOSED,name=proj_c,goal=,startDate= 2017-01-01T04:00:26.231Z,endDate= 2017-01-13T14:36:00.000Z,completeDate= 2017-02-13T14:07:09.739Z,sequence=003]', 'com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@76d3dba0[id=004,rapidViewId=24,state=CLOSED,name=proj_d,goal=,startDate=2018-01-01T04:00:26.231Z,endDate= 2018-01-13T14:36:00.000Z,completeDate= 2018-02-13T14:07:09.739Z,sequence=004]', 'com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@307a51a2[id=005,rapidViewId=24,state=CLOSED,name=proj_e,goal=,startDate=2019-01-01T04:00:26.231Z,endDate= 2019-01-13T14:36:00.000Z,completeDate= 2019-02-13T14:07:09.739Z,sequence=005]']})
df["id"] = df["value"].str.findall(r"id\=(\d+),")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                               value   id
0  com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprin...  001
1  com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprin...  002
2  com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprin...  003
3  com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprin...  004
4  com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprin...  005
```

---

If your DF contains all values in a single list use.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"value": [['com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@339ba62[id=001,rapidViewId=24,state=CLOSED,name=proj_a,goal=,startDate=2015-01-01T04:00:26.231Z,endDate=2015-01-13T14:36:00.000Z,completeDate=2015-02-13T14:07:09.739Z,sequence=001]', 'com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@10b316d8[id=002,rapidViewId=24,state=CLOSED,name=proj_b,goal=,startDate=2016-01-01T04:00:26.231Z,endDate= 2016-01-13T14:36:00.000Z,completeDate= 2016-02-13T14:07:09.739Z,sequence=002]', 'com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@2a13ba77[id=003,rapidViewId=24,state=CLOSED,name=proj_c,goal=,startDate= 2017-01-01T04:00:26.231Z,endDate= 2017-01-13T14:36:00.000Z,completeDate= 2017-02-13T14:07:09.739Z,sequence=003]', 'com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@76d3dba0[id=004,rapidViewId=24,state=CLOSED,name=proj_d,goal=,startDate=2018-01-01T04:00:26.231Z,endDate= 2018-01-13T14:36:00.000Z,completeDate= 2018-02-13T14:07:09.739Z,sequence=004]', 'com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@307a51a2[id=005,rapidViewId=24,state=CLOSED,name=proj_e,goal=,startDate=2019-01-01T04:00:26.231Z,endDate= 2019-01-13T14:36:00.000Z,completeDate= 2019-02-13T14:07:09.739Z,sequence=005]']]})
df["id"] = df["value"].apply(",".join).str.findall(r"id\=(\d+),").apply(",".join)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                               value                   id
0  [com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Spri...  001,002,003,004,005
```